App is not running in Android Studio Emulator
I am not able to get the app working after I click run in the Android Studio. This is happening after some changes in the AndroidManifest.xml file. Have pasted the code as well as output image below for the reference. Any help would be appreciated.

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.restaraunt">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="Samba Express"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Restaraunt"
        >
        <activity
            android:name=".StarterActivity"
            android:label="Starters"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>

I am working on Intent- Moving to new activity, so I have to make some changes in the AndroidManifest.xml file. After that, I am not able to get the app working on emulator.

Are there any errors in Logcat? If so, please add them to your question.

It would help if you can add error log or what exactly are you trying to achieve. And how are you trying to open StarterActivity from MainActivity.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

We definitely need logs to know more.
But from the first look and I don't know if this could be a problem, but why are you using android:exported="true" for StarterActivity. It's used when you want it to be launched by components of other application. And it looks like you are not using intent filter so you don't really need it.

Hi @Mayank Pandit,
Thank you for your reply. This android:exported="true is something by default, it was present in AndroidMainfest.xml file, I did not add or change anything. However as you mentioned, I removed android: exported= "True" but still the "App keep stopping".
Meanwhile, can you let me know on how to send you the "log" from "logcat" since some of the lines in those log are pretty long and will align differently after I paste those log lines here and also to add there are character limit in comments section of stack overflow.

@RoshanR , We would just need logs for the part where the app is crashing. We won't need a full logs. You can use soft-wrap of logcat and take a screenshot so everything is in one window or just copy and paste the crashing part from the log and update your question. I think the character limit for question on stack overflow is 30,000 so you can add plenty of info in your question. Also, what did you add/change in your manifest that started the crash? If you remove it, does it work?
